# Is it possible to have two Spark process reading a stream in one Delta Table at the same time?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks

I'm receiving data in one Delta Table, and I want to have two consumers process reading on it:

I have in different jars these codes:

1) A Spark process for computing aggregations in real time.

```
val df_aggregations = spark.readStream
     .format("delta")
     .option("ignoreDeletes", "true")
     .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
     .option("checkpointLocation", configuration.delta_aggregation_checkpoint)
     .load(configuration.delta_table)
```

2) A Spark process for obtaining the new values in real time.

```
val df_news = spark.readStream
.format("delta")
.option("ignoreDeletes", "true")
.option("ignoreChanges", "true")
.option("checkpointLocation", configuration.delta_news_checkpoint)
.load(configuration.delta_table)
```

My problem is that I just see one of the process working good, I mean if I run the process 1) first than 2) I see good results of the process 1), however, the I don't see results of the process 2), and if I run the process 2) first, then I see the results of the process 2), but I don't see process 1) results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have N consumers process reading on the same Delta Table, just you need to have different checkpoints files for each process.